# Displaying Results of Add/ Delete operation dynamically in HTML using ANGULAR JS and Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having an employee form where the user can add the employee details,search for employee details and delete those details .  I have written  separate functions for add,search and delete operations inside the controller . Whenever the user adds an employee / deletes an employee . I want the result list to be updated dynamically (Added employee should be shown on result list, deleted employee should not be shown on result list ). How can I achieve this . for example after the delete operation response is successful , should I call the search function again ? .Is there any other way to do these . I am using Angular JS and Spring MVC

This is my Controller Code for Search

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/services/employee/search/'+Systems+"", searchCriteria)
.then(function(response) {
   $scope.searchresponse= [];
   $scope.searchresponse = response.data.items;
   if (response.data && response.data.items.length != 0) {
        $scope.searchresponse = response.data.items.map(function (x) {
            x.selected = false;
            return x;
        });
        console.log($scope.searchresponse);
   } 
   else {
        $scope.showerror = true;
        $scope.ErrorMsg ="There is no record matching your criteria."
   }
});
```

This is my search Response From API

```
{
    "items": [{
       "employeeId": "ABC",
       "type": "D",
       "alive": "Yes"
    }, {
       "employeeId": "DEF",
       "type": "A",
       "alive": "Yes"
    }],
    "more": false
}
```

This is my Controller call for Delete

```
 var data1=["ABC", "NPK"];
$http.delete('http://localhost:8080/services/employee/delete/'+Systems+"", {data:{"idList":data1},headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}} )
.then(function(response) {
console.log("testing");
// - here i would like to implement code to remove all the fields that belong to eomployee id ABC,NPK from result page  
        });
```

I am using selectall/deselect all checkbox to give user option to remove multiple items

Comment: If you are storing those employees in a collection, in your successful response handler from the server, you can just add the new item that it returns into the collection you already have on the client. The same can be done when you delete. Just splice out the one that you want to remove. The only caveat is that you would not ever know on the client is the backend was changed in some other way by another user for example.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can follow this example http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54475/basic-and-simple-view-add-edit-and-delete-functionality

Comment: As of now i  am able to  search and display the results from database  ,insert the employees into database  , delete employees from database .When i do a delete even though the employess is deleted from database , it is not getting removed from the html . I am planning to call search operation again so the result list gets updated . Is this a good way of doing things ?

Comment: Can you post your code? It will be easy to identify the issue.

Comment: @NagaveerGowda I have updated my code with what i want to achieve could you please have a look now

Comment: @Praveen Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes it has been resolved ! Thanks

Comment: @NagaveerGowda I am facing issues can you help me solve this !

Comment: @Praveen have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose your `employee` has `name` and `id` properties, and you have some http resource uri to identify an employee, e.g.

```
http://youservice/employees/123
```

and a service to delete him/her.

In your view, you display the employee list as

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="employee in employeeList track by employee.id">  
      {{employee.name}} <button ng-click="deleteEmployee(employee.id)">delete</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In your controller, the function called when the user press the *delete* button on an employee can be

```
$scope.employeeList = [...];

$scope.deleteEmployee = function(employeeId) {
    let empUri = 'http://youservice/employees/'+employeeId;
    $http.delete(empUri).then(function(response) {
       // delete is successful, remove employee from the list 
       let empIndex = $scope.employeeList.findIndex(e => e.id === employeeId);
       $scope.employeeList.splice(empIndex, 1);
    }, function(responseError) {
       // delete is in error. Display an alert...
    });
}
```

The list shall be refreshed in the view.

---

UPDATE
In order to remove several employees from the search result, you can just filter the search list, e.g (from your code):

```
var data1=["ABC", "NPK"];
$http.delete(/* delete service url and data */).then(function(response) {
    // Filter out employees from data1  
    let empList = $scope.searchresponse.filter(emp => {
        // Is emp not in data1 ?
        return !data1.some(remEmpId => remEmpId == emp.employeeId);
    });
    $scope.searchresponse = empList;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for Commenting , i have updated my question . Can you help me  now with how to splice out employess based on their  id's from result

Comment: Based on the info in the question he looks to want to splice an array of elements from the array. Additionally in your `ng-repeat` you could pass in the `$index` so you don't have to search for it later.

Comment: @Danny yes that's a possibility, somewhat simper.

Comment: When i try this, whole items in the result gets spliced out

Comment: Its not removing still .. when i do a console.log on empList i am able to see still the item is present inside that

Comment: from your code above, `$scope.searchresponse` contains an array `[{employeeId:....}, {employeeId:...}]` , which is the result of the `map(function(x) {...})`. Is that right ?

Comment: My bad! `data` is just a list of employee ids, the comparator function should not contain `remEmp.employeeId` but just `remEmp`. I corrected and renamed `remEmp` into `remEmpId`.

Comment: I will try this !! . I solved it like this var data1=["ABC","NPK"];
var items=searchresponse[0].items;
for(i in items){
    if(data1.indexOf(items[i].employeeId)!=-1){
        items.splice(i,1);
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove data from the response List

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.employeeList.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.employeeList[i].employeeId == employeeId) {
    $scope.employeeList.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}
```

Have a look at [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/5mn6ppg1bqwRKAyyYZyg?p=preview)

Hope this Helps!!!